# Typescript emitted declarations cannot find name of global interface

Tags: typescript

This issue is in a private CDN library. I want to generate TypeScript declaration files for development use by apps that integrate the library. My issue is that my generated declaration files have 'cannot find name' errors regarding correctly-defined global interfaces.

First, the CDN library's compiler options have `emitDeclarationOnly` and `declaration` true. This correctly puts the declarations into the directory "types."

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "types"

    // .... paths etc. omitted
  }
```

Second, I have a global interface declaration file that declares about 7 or 8 different interfaces.

```
// global.ts
    interface ComponentToggle {
        component: HTMLElement,

        // other properties here
    }

    // more interfaces here
```

Third, the original JavaScript source files are able to use the global interfaces inside the JSDocs. These files use JSDocs to define their TypeScript information. They compile to `.d.ts` files without any errors.

```
// otherfile.js
    /** Removes active state from all options.
     *
     * @param toggle {ComponentToggle} the parent element toggle message
     */
    inactivate( { component } ) {
        if ( component.contains( this ) ) {
            this.getOptions( true ).forEach( option => option.inactivate() );
        }
    }
```

The generated d.ts files are all correct.

```
// global.d.ts
    interface ComponentToggle {
        component: HTMLElement,

        // identical to the ts file
    }

// otherfile.d.ts
    /** Removes active state from all options.
     *
     * @param toggle {ComponentToggle} the parent element toggle message
     */
    inactivate({ component }: ComponentToggle): void;
```

Now we get to the problem. When trying to use `otherfile.d.ts`, there is a new TypeScript error:

`TS2304: Cannot find name 'ComponentToggle'.`

Can anyone explain what is going on? How is it that the global interface `ComponentToggle` cannot be found here when it was literally just used to generate this file?

EDIT:
Mainly, I notice there is an issue as soon as I open affected d.ts files, because the WebStorm parser flags them.

As requested, here is the tsconfig of the app I am using to test this, which is also not a TypeScript application. I don't have ownership of any of the apps that will be consuming this library. Because this is for CDN use, the library is defined in the source code using local paths starting with /xxxyyy/ (see below) that are defined as "externals" in Webpack and also as proxy paths in Karma. The build (minus `tsc`) and unit tests run fine, and the types of the library are correctly found. WebStorm correctly displays the types and hints for the files that do not have this issue, and running `tsc` outputs the exact same errors that WebStorm displays when I open the files.

*The consuming application:*

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "ci-output",
    "unitTest",
    "tutorials",
    "lib"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "types",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [ "AppMain", "./src/component/app-main.js" ],
      "/xxxyyy/libraryname.min.js": [ "libraryname", "./node_modules/@xxxyyy/libraryname/types/index.d.ts" ],
      "/xxxyyy/libraryname.js": [ "libraryname", "./node_modules/@xxxyyy/libraryname/types/index.d.ts" ]
    }
  }
}
```

*The library itself:*

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "ci-output",
    "conf",
    "jsdocTemplate",
    "unitTest",
    "tutorials"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "types",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": [ "MainComponent", "./src/component/MainComponent.js" ]
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 2
Okay, since nobody seems to have any answers for me, I'll try another approach. Every single one of these globals fits one of the following categories:

1. A "polyfill" because TypeScript's built-in definitions of Window are missing things.

- window.CustomEventListener: see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28357
- window.ResizeObserverEntry: see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37861

2. Definitions of what some functions expect to receive as object parameters.

- In the example above, I defined ComponentToggle because there are many functions that take a single object as their parameter, and that object has a specific set of properties that will be destructured. I want to define those properties so that the consuming app will know how to call the functions.

Is there *anything I can do* to meet requirements #1 and #2 that does not involve creating a global.ts file?

If not, how do I get the generated global.d.ts file to get consumed by WebStorm and the app? Do I set configurations in "paths", "types", "typeRoots", or something else I haven't heard of yet?

Also, the comments on this question seem to assume I know things. I know nothing at all about TypeScript. I could very well be making the most beginner of errors here.

Comment: could you share the .tsconfig of the application which uses this library, ensure you're not using typeroots : as @types/ folder

Comment: Can you share with us how you declared the global interface? I didn't saw the `global` keyword in your example. Thanks

Comment: You mention "I have a global interface declaration file" - are you using the [`declare global`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html) augmentation in your typings? If you are able to provide a minimilistic reproduction repository, that would significantly help narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @concision It is just a file that has these interfaces in it one after another. If I try to use `declare global` in the file to surround them, I get the error `TS2669: Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.` I'm not a TypeScript developer, so dumb it down please. :)

Comment: @concision My file looks like this one: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone has a better answer than this. I do not really like this solution because it makes the consuming app have to put information about my library in two different places in their `tsconfig`.

I dug around a thousand places. Eventually, I found something about triple slash directives. When I manually put a triple slash directive `/// <reference path="./global.d.ts"` at the top of the index.d.ts file, everything magically started working. I then researched further on how tsconfig had replaced triple slash directives. Here is the answer I was looking for:

*The consuming application:*

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "node_modules/@xxxyyy/libraryname/types/global.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    // I had to remove "node_modules" from this list
    "ci-output",
    "unitTest",
    "tutorials",
    "lib"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "types",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [ "AppMain", "./src/component/app-main.js" ],
      "/xxxyyy/libraryname.min.js": [ "libraryname", "./node_modules/@xxxyyy/libraryname/types/index.d.ts" ]
    }
  }
}
```